# what is the alternative of angular.isString() in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

I am working on a project in angular2 and curious to know if there is any mean by which I can use angularjs functionalities in my angular2 application.

for ex.

**in angularjs**, I used to do following operations:

1. *angular.isString(value)*
2. *angular.isArray(value)*
3. *angular.copy(value)*

I just want to know that is there any module or package which can help me do above operations **in angular2/typescript**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use JavaScript:

- isString

Simple

```
  typeof foo === 'string'
```

- angular.isArray(value)

Simple

```
Array.isArray(value)
```

- angular.copy(value)

Simple

```
Object.assign({},value)
```

Comment: Object.assign does not provide deep copying the object,any inputs on that?

Comment: @BhushanGadekar I agree with bali's recommendation

Comment: @basarat thanks,does loadash provide isObject method too?

Comment: I don't know Angular deeply, but for strings one should be aware of [String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects), so using `typeof foo.valueOf() === 'string'` might be a good idea.
Cloning objects can be deep or shallow; in browsers, [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) can be used for deep cloning.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Except for `copy`, angular2 actually provides the `isString` and `isArray` (and a lot more) functions from `"@angular/common/src/facade/lang"`. To use these you have to import them like this:</strike>

```
import {isString, isArray} from "@angular/common/src/facade/lang";
```

But, the body of these functions are the same as basarat mentioned, and this import is no longer available. Sooo, use the solution above :)

Comment: Just to mention: Importing from `src`is discouraged. It's considered private implementation of the package.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks! I did create my own wrapper for functions like these, because I figured as much, but i never found any documentation where it states that you should not directly use these

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nice addition, i gave my thumb up for support ;)

Comment: For what it is worth; that code, '@angular/common/src/facade/lang' is not in the Angular 4 directories I installed via NodeJS.

Comment: @JeffryHouser You are right, it was available a long time ago (around the time when this question was asked), but not anymore. Way to dig up an old answer and downvote

Comment: @PierreDuc Do I detect sarcasm? This came up in a search for a different issue. I was looking for an isObject() function.  I ended up using `import {isObject} from "rxjs/util/isObject";`; I suspect there are similar functions for isString and isArray, but haven't looked.

Comment: Nooo, I would never use sarcasm ;) anyways, angular natively doesn't export these kind of functions anymore, like they did in angular1. You should either use another utility library, or create your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lodash-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) (ES module import support for lodash) to do the following:

```
import { isString } from 'lodash-es';

console.log(isString('') === true);
```

I prefer this over the accepted answer of `typeof foo === 'string'` because string literals are prone to mistakes and are harder to minify.